# How to correctly deal with 302 status code

Tags: asana

Im not sure how i should deal with a HTTP_STATUS of 302 in my response to an API request?

Im trying to write a small Node.js script and i have a feeling this is to do with the HTTPS upgrade of the request i send?

Any help would be great

Comment: Can you provide details about the request you're making and the response you're getting?

Comment: sorry didn't make myself clear. My Node http request returns a 302 response and then does nothing else. i take it that i will have to follow the redirect myself ?

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing (specifically) to do with HTTPS, it just a temporary redirect.

Read [this article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302).