# How to handle status 302?

Tags: javascript, redirect, xmlhttprequest

When I execute a simple *XML HTTP Request* from my server using the code below

```
var targetUrl = "http://server/Service1.svc?input1=uno&input2=duo";
document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "<br>commencing";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "<br>callbacking";
  alert(xhr.responseText);
}

xhr.open("GET", targetUrl);
document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "<br>finishing";

xhr.send();
```

I get status code 302 in the console of FireBug. According to [this W3 article](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), status code 302 means that the resource is temporarily redirected. I'm not fully certain on what that mean in my case because when I type my URL into the FireFox, I get the response as supposed to, looking great.

There are numerous articles regarding this issue but I can't get it straight. For instance, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420686/how-to-correctly-deal-with-302-status-code) only restates the definition of the status code. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299021/ajax-and-status-302) suggests to use *HEAD* instead of *GET* but that's not an option in my case (unless absolutely necessary). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524039/problems-with-xmlhttprequest-status-302) it's even claimed that the status code 302 **automatically** leads to a correct redirect to the plac ewhere the page moved to (resulting in status code 200), which in my case isn't true.

I've tried looking at `xhr.getRespoonseHeader("Content-Type")` but, apparently, it's `null`.

I'm stuck. What can I do about my problem?

Comment: Do you have a htaccess redirecting non-www to www?

Comment: Have you looked at a tool like Fiddler and see what happens? I am guessing your server is correcting a url, but without seeing code, live demo, it is hard to say.

Comment: @MrCode Not sure. I haven't set that explicitly and I don't know how to check if it's enabled (installed?) by default. Are we talking server side (which I'll have a slight problem changing) or client side (where I have full freedom of action)?

Comment: @epascarello Not, not Fiddler, only FireBug. The code is posted in the update to my question. I didn't do that before because I don't want to be that guy who posts **everything** and say "*please help*". I want to learn from this, you see. I just realize that I need a slight push. Maybe not so slight... :)

Comment: @CRMconfusee You can tell by the presence of a .htaccess file on the server itself - it will be a plain text file that contains 'rules' for redirection and other little goodies, you (*generally*) wont be able to tell from the client-side. I've given you a +1 on your question as it's an interesting question, but most of all - I'm really impressed by your attitude in that last comment. It's refreshing to see someone not wanting to be... *that guy*. ;)

Comment: @FergusMorrow I have very limited access to the server, so I won't be able to check for the existence of that file (unless it's  viewable by e.g. *http://server/beep.htaccess* or some facility available remotely). Assuming that (a) such a file exists and (b) such file doesn't exist - how can I analyze, debug and resolve my issue? Any suggestions would be great at this point. I'd put a bounty on the question but I lack reputation, still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have to do with some internal redirect on the IIS server. I'd also check if the service is installed in an application pool.

Also, it might be something like a protocol switch or domain ambiguity (i.e. secured/unsecured http and/ or with/sans w3 prefix).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your server is either:

- Redirecting non-www `http://` to www `http://www.`
- Redirecting unsecured HTTP `http://` to secure HTTPS `https://`

In your web browser, view `http://server/Service1.svc?input1=uno&input2=duo` and observe the address bar. Does it change in any way at all? Check to see if `www` is added, or `https`.

You could also change your javascript URL to the www version, and https version, to see if either fixes it.

**Edit**: based on what you said about https, I think it is redirecting http to https. Your ajax code is not right so that will explain why the callback isn't working.

You need to use the `onreadystatechange` event (not onload) and check for state `4` which means it completed:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4){
            document.getElementById("console").innerHTML += "<br>callbacking";
            alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.open("GET", targetUrl, true);
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: I'm making hte call from URL line using no-www and no-s-in-http version. Are you saying that the server maybe redirects such a call to an other resource that is secure/www'ed?

Comment: I've tested the changes. Switching to *www* prefix gave no difference. Switching to *https* gave the only difference that the response header doesn't show. The callback isn't executed in any case... Is it manageable from JS or do I need to handle it by asking the server administrator to change some configuration?

Comment: @CRMconfusee see my edit. Your server must be redirecting to https.